# Distinct Count from a Many Table in a One-To-Many Relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a newbie to SQL so I apologize if this query is basic.

I have a patient data table that has singularly occurring fields i.e. chart_number, Name, with the unique identifier of zzabstractlink.   I have another table of procedures and there could be up to 20 per patient with the data in long format.

I am also linking to another multi occurring table, diagnoses, so should I be creating 3 different datasets with all the fields and derived fields (like above for c-sections) and then link them together via a union statement? Or will whatever the solution for the procedures work with the diagnoses?

All assistance greatly appreciated, thanks.

note: for the code provided, this pulled over a case from the intervention table for as many records as there were interventions and not just once, which is what I would like.

S.

[patient table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUalS.png)

| zzabstractlink | name | patient_service | admit_date | disch_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | Smith, John | 30 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-05 |
| 222222 | Jones, Frank | 30 | 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-15 |
| 333333 | Green, Joni | 55 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-10 |
| 444444 | Black, Mitzi | 51 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-03 |
| 555555 | Cameron, Sally | 10 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-05 |

[procedure table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4hMm.png)

| zzabstractlink | PxOccur | PxCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 1 | INV89DA |
| 111111 | 2 | ITA35HAJ2 |
| 111111 | 3 | ITA80DA |
| 222222 | 1 | IAN27JA |
| 222222 | 2 | 1BM72LA |
| 222222 | 3 | 1FR89WJAK |
| 333333 | 1 | 1RM89LA |
| 333333 | 2 | 1RF89LA |
| 444444 | 1 | 5MD60AA |

[diagnosis table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyWQc.png)

| zzabstractlink | DxOccur | DxCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 1 | K711 |
| 111111 | 2 | R458 |
| 222222 | 1 | K358 |
| 222222 | 2 | I651 |
| 333333 | 1 | N811 |
| 333333 | 2 | N816 |
| 444444 | 1 | O70101 |
| 444444 | 2 | Z3700 |
| 555555 | 1 | I500 |
| 555555 | 2 | E785 |
| 555555 | 3 | R64 |

[desired outcome]

| zzabstractlink | cs(derived field from px) | prev_cs(derived field from dx) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 0 | 0 |
| 222222 | 0 | 0 |
| 333333 | 0 | 0 |
| 444444 | 1 | 1 |
| 555555 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Don't join to Px and Dx in the same query, as that would cause much duplication. Like you mention, you need to UNION them together. In regards to your Patient table, i imagine that pulls much different data than what's found in your Px or Dx tables; therefore, treat that one separate. Just depends what you want to accomplish, but I would keep Patient table as it's own query, or just join that to the Px query and to the Dx query if that returns what you seek.

Comment: Please provide more information like desired output or example of your table so we can better understand your problem and come up with more accurate solution.

Comment: Tip: Rather than describing the table columns, it's best to just *show* the table columns and some sample data.  (Obviously with sensitive info, never post real data! Where needed, substitute dummy values that are representative of the underlying data, like "John Doe" for a name or 123456789 for a uniquely identifying number, etc...)

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  So how do I create 3 different queries in the same SQL code to then link them?    How do I repost information to show you the table structures?  Thanks.

Comment: I attached a sample of each  table.  The patient table only has singularly occurring fields like birthdate, name, healthcard number.  ZZAbstractLink is the common linking field in all tables.  I purposely had patient 555555 not have a procedure which is valid but all will have a diagnosis.  For procedures, I would want to create a case where if procedure = '5MD60%' then csection = 1 and only have the case show up once.  I hope this makes sense, thanks again for any assistance.

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know....do I need to repost?

Comment: You can just [edit] your question.

Comment: Using the sample data, please add the expected results (as text, in table format).

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance...hopefully I've done it correctly in showing you what I am looking for.   From the diagnosis table I want to loop through the codes per chart and only count it once if it meets the criteria for "previous c-section" and from the procedure side I look through the procedures to determine "c-section".  Then union link a subset of the "patient file" to link to these two queries based on the multi occurring fields.  Thanks.

Comment: You get cs = 1 for 444444, because there exists a row with `'5MD60AA' LIKE '5MD60%'`. But why is prev_cs = 1, too? What is the rule for this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow how you're deriving the "cs" values. For zzabstractlink=444444 all we see is several alpha numeric strings that don't appear to have any obvious relation to each other  ("5MD60AA", "Z3700", "O70101"). Could you elaborate?

Comment: @SOS: I found this hidden in the comments: "For procedures, I would want to create a case where if procedure = '5MD60%' then csection = 1". shellp, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71730820/edit) your request and add all the information that is needed. Don't put them in the comments only. Let people see what you are really asking. And you haven't answered how to get the prev_cs result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you get to the prev_cs value. But as to the cs value, you want an `EXISTS` or `IN` clause:

```
select
  zzabstractlink,
  zzabstractlink in (select zzabstractlink from procedures where pxcode like '5MD60%')
    as cs
from patients
order by zzabstractlink;
```

In MySQL true = 1, false = 0. The `IN` or `EXISTS` clause will hence be 1 if you find a matching row and 0 otherwise.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00501fd3d98f63a35ad2c4cb527c7f8e

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work.   The code produces an error.

Comment: It runs for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00501fd3d98f63a35ad2c4cb527c7f8e. What error message are you getting? "This produces an error" doesn't tell me much, and I don't understand why you keep the error message a secret. I noticed that procedure is a reserved word, so your table name must be different or you need backtics or double quotes around it. Have you changed my table names to the actual names?

Comment: I've changed my table names to plural now in order not to use the reserved word "procedure", but you will have to use your real table names of course.